# Vue chain multiple filters in getter

Tags: vue.js, vuex

On a Getter I need to filter an array and return values that match 2 conditions. 
I need to return item_categories that don't have an item_category_location equal to current location or don't have item_category_locations at all.

```
 unaddedItemCategories(state, getters, rootState) {
                let otherLocations = state.item_categories
                    .filter((item_category) =>
                        item_category.item_category_locations.some((item_category_location) => item_category_location.location_id !== rootState.currentLocation.id))
                let noLocations = state.item_categories
                    .filter(item_category => item_category.item_category_locations.length == 0)
                return otherLocations, noLocations

            },
```

The 2 filters work fine. How can I chain them to create a new array?

Comment: Why are you using a [comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) in your return statement ?

Comment: The return statement does not really makes sense, it's just to show what I want to return

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer if you simply used a single `filter` with a logical OR `||` instead of filtering twice ? If would also half the number of iterations.

Comment: Yes but I couldn't get the syntax right to add a || in OtherLocations. But sure would be better. If you can show it in answer I'll accept that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
return [...otherLocations, ...noLocations]
```